# Search in Select List

Tags: php, html, select, search

Currently creating this project and having problems on how to create a search in select list. I would like to search from option values. how can i create this kind of search on select list?

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);


//connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "waterdis_stbwd");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
echo "Unable to connect to database server";
}

//query database for items to populate
$sql = "SELECT id FROM usrs";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo '<select id="slct">';
echo '<option value="">Select ID</option>';
while($id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo "<option>{$id['id']}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a plugin, like select2

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);


//connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "waterdis_stbwd");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
echo "Unable to connect to database server";
}

//query database for items to populate
$sql = "SELECT id FROM usrs";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo '<select id="slct">';
echo '<option value="">Select ID</option>';
while($id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo "<option value="{$id['id']}">{$id['id']}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';


?>
```